# CSV to Dictionary Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file like this one:

```
ALBERO; SHAFT
ALBERINO; SHAFT
MAGGIORATO; EXTRA WIDE
```

I need to open that file and convert to a dictionary with the following structure:

```
glossario={"ALBERO" : "SHAFT", 
           "ALBERINO" : "SHAFT",
           "MAGGIORATO" : "EXTRA WIDE" }
```

I tried to setup the following code, but the output it's not what I expected:

```
glossario= []
with open(glossarioFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf, delimiter=';') 
    for line in csvReader: 
        glossario.append(line)
```

Anyone has some suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: What output did you get? Maybe because `[]` creates a list not a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for it to work :

```py
glossario= {}
with open(glossarioFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=';') 
    for line in csvReader: 
        glossario[line[0]] = line[1]
```

I update the dictionnary with the new key/value pair every iteration.

Comment: however, be aware that if the csv has two rows with the same keys in the first column, the final dictionary will only keep the value from the last row for the key. e.g. - `[(1, 2), (1, 3)]` will only retain `{1: 3}`.

Answer (score 2):

`DictReader` doesn't do what you want, the keys in the output are the headers (A.K.A the first line of the csv), and the values are the values in the same column as the header https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

You want to use a regular `csv.reader` and set the values of each line to a dictionary.

```
import csv

glossario = {}
glossario_file_path = 'glossario.csv'
with open(glossario_file_path, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=';')
    for line in reader:
        key = line[0]
        value = line[1]
        glossario[key] = value
```

This is how the `glossario` variable looks like

```
{'ALBERO': ' SHAFT', 'ALBERINO': ' SHAFT', 'MAGGIORATO': ' EXTRA WIDE'}
```

Notice that the values of the dict contain whitespaces, so you might want to add
`value = line[1].strip()` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've used python [Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to write more pythonic code.

```py
import csv


glossario = {}
glossario_file_path = 'your_file_name.csv'
with open(glossario_file_path, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=';')
    glossario = {key: value for key, value in csv_reader}

print(glossario)
```

```py
{'ALBERO': ' SHAFT', 'ALBERINO': ' SHAFT', 'MAGGIORATO': ' EXTRA WIDE'}
```